# Number not converting to string

Tags: python

My program prints till 99 but after that input isn't converting into words i.e.
if I put 450 as input then this is giving error. Please help me with this

```
words_upto_19=['','one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 
 'ten', 'eleven' , 'twelve' , 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 
 'nineteen']

words_upto_tens =['','','twenty','thirty','fourty','fifty','sixty','seventy','eighty','ninety']
words_upto_999=['hundred and ']

a=int(input('enter the no. between 1 and 100:'))
if a==0:
    output='zero'

#for converting numbers above 1 till 19 into words.
elif a<=19:
    output=words_upto_19[a]

#for converting numbers above 20 till 99 into words.
elif a<=99:
    output= words_upto_tens[a//10] +" "+words_upto_19[a%10]

#for converting numbers above 99 till 999 into words.
elif a<=999:
    output=words_upto_999[a//100]+''+ words_upto_tens[a//10] +''+words_upto_19[a%10]
    
else:
    output='please enter the no. between 1 to 100'

print(output)
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use libraries or only from scratch?

Comment: You can use [a library](https://pypi.org/project/num2words/)

Answer (score 0):

Your logic for the block `a <=999` is wrong.

1. If say input is 450, `a//100` would be `4` but `words_upto_999` list has only one element. So, `words_upto_999[a//100]` would raise an exception.

   You can just get the the multiple of hundred using `words_upto_19[a//100] + " hundred and " + ...`. Also you can get rid of `words_upto_999`
2. For the next part (i.e. `words_upto_tens[a//10]`) you need to change that as well. Say for the same input `450`, `a//10` becomes `45` and `words_upto_tens[a//10]` will again raise an exception. You can use `words_upto_tens[(a%100)//10]` instead.

So, the code for that block can be -

```
elif a<=999:
    output=words_upto_19[a//100] + ' hundred and ' + words_upto_tens[(a%100)//10] + ' ' + words_upto_19[a%10]
```

Then again it is not entirely correct as numbers > 100 which has second digit as 1 (e.g. 311, 519 etc.) will not be printed correctly. But I think you can fix that yourself.